# RDD partitioning logic

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to understand RDD partitioning logic. RDD is partitioned across nodes but wants to understand how this partitioning logic works.

I have VM with 4 cores assigned to it. I created two RDD , one from HDFS and one from parallelize operation.

[image]

First time two partition got created but in second operation 4 partition got created.

I checked no of blocks allocated to file - it was 1 block as file is very small but when I created RDD on that file , it shows two partitions. Why is this ? I read somewhere that partitioning also depends on no of core which 4 in my case which still does not satisfies that output.

Can someone help to understand this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does partitioning work for data from files on HDFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011574/how-does-partitioning-work-for-data-from-files-on-hdfs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full signature of `textFile` is:

```
textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String]
```

With the second argument, `minPartitions`, you can set the minimum amount of partitions you want to get. As you can see, by default it is set to `defaultMinPartitions`, which in turn is defined as:

```
def defaultMinPartitions: Int = math.min(defaultParallelism, 2)
```

The value of `defaultParalellism` is configured with the `spark.default.parallelism` setting, which by default depends on your number of cores when running Spark in local mode. This is 4 in your case, so you get `min(4, 2)`, which is why you get 2 partitions.

Comment: great answers. How did you figure that "The value of defaultParalellism is configured with the spark.default.parallelism setting" ??

Comment: Firstly by assuming the naming of the variable and the setting is not accidental ;) but by following the code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2321 sets it from the taskscheduler, which here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSchedulerImpl.scala#L517 gets it from the backend which here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/local/LocalSchedulerBackend.scala#L144 gets it from the setting