# Data frame re partition is not happening as expected

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running below code in spark to create table temp1 with number of parttion 200 . But while i am checking the actual number of partition by creating an rdd out of temp1 table its coming to be more than 200.
How is this possible , am i missing any thing .It would be really helpful if any one can tell me ,if i am missing any thing !! Thanks

```
  val TransDataFrame = hiveContext.sql(
      s""" SELECT *
            FROM uacc.TRANS
            WHERE PROD_SURRO_ID != 0
            AND MONTH_ID >= 201401
            AND MONTH_ID <= 201403
            AND CRE_DT   <=  '2016-11-13'

         """).repartition(200,$"NDC").registerTempTable("temp")


   hiveContext.sql(
      s"""
          CREATE TABLE uacc.temp1
          AS SELECT * FROM temp
        """) 


val df = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM uacc.temp1")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions
1224
```

Answer (score 0):

As you create the table `uacc.temp1` you actually write your dataframe to hdfs, now as you load that table again, the number of partitions is controlled by the number of hdfs files (more specific: file splits), see [How does partitioning work for data from files on HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011574/how-does-partitioning-work-for-data-from-files-on-hdfs)

Comment: If you check TransDataFrame it  will have 200 partitions . Your are writing it to hdfs loading back to new rdd which will give no.of partitions based on number of  blocks hdfs used to save  table.