# Does Spark have a limit for how many files can be loaded simultaneously?

Tags: apache-spark

I use the following code to load data from `HDFS`:

```
spark
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .format("parquet")
  .load("hdfs")
```

when I tried to load about 3,000,000 files, I will get a exception as:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3072)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2867)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1639)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult.value(TaskResult.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1948)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:62)
```

The file format is `.snappy.parquet`, and size for each file was about `100KB`, for each file the schema is as:

```
id, String
type, String
att, String
pre, String
tag, Map[String, String]
day, Int
```

the partition information:

```
.repartition($"day", $"type", $"att")
  .write
  .partitionBy("day", "type", "att")
```

When I tried about 107,000 files, works fine.

For this step, the spark just load the metadata of files, why need so many memory space?
Is there a limit for how many files can load from `HDFS`?

Comment: Can you try running with KryoSerializer ? It has less memory footprint compared to Java Serializer

Comment: Given this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011574/how-does-spark-partitioning-work-on-files-in-hdfs, I get the impression many millions of partitions will be made. That strikes me as huge overhead.