# What is the difference between partitioning and bucketing in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, bucket, data-partitioning

I try to optimize a join query between two spark dataframes, let's call them df1, df2 (join on common column "SaleId").
df1 is very small (5M) so I broadcast it among the nodes of the spark cluster.
df2 is very large (200M rows) so I tried to bucket/repartition it by "SaleId".

In Spark, what is the difference between partitioning the data by column and bucketing the data by column?

for example:

partition:

```
df2 = df2.repartition(10, "SaleId")
```

bucket:

```
df2.write.format('parquet').bucketBy(10, 'SaleId').mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('bucketed_table'))
```

After each one of those techniques I just joined df2 with df1.

I can't figure out which of those is the right technique to use.
Thank you

Comment: Answer not to your liking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***repartition*** is for using as part of an Action in the **same** Spark Job.
>
> ***bucketBy*** is for output, write. And thus for avoiding shuffling in the **next** Spark App, typically as part of ETL. Think of JOINs.
>   See
>   https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4861715144695760/2994977456373837/5701837197372837/latest.html
>   which is an excellent concise read. bucketBy tables can only be read
>   by Spark though currently.

Comment: but we also can write a dataframe to Disk/S3 after the repartition and when we will read it in the next spark job it will be still re-partitioned. Am I wrong?

Comment: No guarantee on reading in. Need to use correct settings. Read the link. Why would this be catered for otherwise?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011574/how-does-spark-partitioning-work-on-files-in-hdfs