# Partition by columns: data being truncated to another partition

Tags: pyspark, partitioning, azure-databricks

I'm using `repartitionByRange` in PySpark while saving over 2,000+ CSV's.

```
df.repartitionByRange(<no of unique values of col>, col).write\
        .option("sep", "|")\
        .option("header", "true")\
        .option("quote",  '"')\
        .option("escape", '"')\
        .option("nullValue", "null")\
        .option("quoteAll", "true")\
        .mode('overwrite')\
        .csv(path)
```

And then renaming each partition with the unique id of column  that they contain. However, around 1-2% of the CSV's being generated have more than one unique id. Please assist resolving this issue of incorrect repartitioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control how your files are written you must use the `bucketBy`method instead. `repartition` does not impact the saved file, simply the processing.

You can refer to this post for additional information :
[What is the difference between partitioning and bucketing in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857453/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-in-spark)

So something like this :

```
df.write.format('parquet').bucketBy(10, 'column')
```