# Why 7 partitions are being determined by Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a parquet directory having 5 files as shown below:

[image]

I am using Spark 2.2 version and reading this directory using below code:

[image]

I am not clear why 7 partitions (alternateDF.rdd().getNumPartitions()) are being determined by Spark when we have 5 files (each less than block size) in the parquet directory? 
5 tasks have input records but the last 2 tasks have 0 input records but non-zero input data. Could you please explain the behavior of each task?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Aman,

You can follow an old question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011574/how-does-spark-partitioning-work-on-files-in-hdfs)

simply put following are the 3 parameters it depends (from above link) on to calculate number of partitions

- `spark.default.parallelism` (roughly translates to #cores available for
  the application)
- `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` (default 128MB)
- `spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes` (default 4MB)

Spark source code to [refer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/DataSourceScanExec.scala#L422-L486)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not able to get this number from above logic.

To simplify the question further I tried using CSV files as input to spark.read function. 

Observations -
5 files in CSV directory (each file of size 40 MB approx) gave me 10 partitions
3 Files in CSV directory (each file of size 60 MB approx) gave me 9 partitions

Unable to understand this Spark behavior

Comment: spark.default.parallelism is 8 and spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes is 128MB

Comment: Did you tested with only one big file and seeing same behavior? or is it only happening with more than one file which less than 128MB?

Comment: I did read one CSV file with 233 MB size, it gave me 2 partitions. But when I load small files then it gives me different number of partitions as mentioned in my last comment. My question is more about small file partitions. How they are computed precisely?